# Sampling 3 out of 7 items; with and without replacement

Tags: probability, statistics

A set of numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) is given. What is the probability of getting 3 odd numbers when choosing 3 numbers among the set of numbers at random?

I'm not sure how to solve a question like this. I'm also not sure if the sets of 3 numbers must be sets of 3 *unique numbers* or if a number can be repeated more than once in a single set. Please try to explain the procedures of solving the question for both cases (unique and non-unique).

Comment: "*I'm also not sure if the sets of 3 numbers must be sets of 3 unique numbers or if a number can be repeated more than once*"  We can't help with that.  Both are common questions.  If you are creating a question for yourself for your work, then you will know ahead of time which it is since it is you who decides which it is.  If someone else posed the question for you to answer, then you should be able to ask that person whether repetition is allowed or not.

Comment: "*Choosing ...* **at random**"  That is imprecise language and ambiguous.  This needs to be clarified (*and such clarification if adequately phrased would also clarify the question of if repetition is allowed*).  The most common possibilities here would be that each subset of three distinct numbers are equally likely to be chosen or that you have three independent uniform random variables picking from the set, $(X,Y,Z)$, making each element in the triple cartesian product $\{1,2,3,\dots,7\}^3$ equally likely

Comment: In each of the most common interpretations, you are dealing with some collection of outcomes, each of whom are equally likely.  Simply count how many "good" outcomes there are and divide by the total number of possible outcomes to get the probability.  (*Warning: This is only valid if the outcomes are equally likely and might not work otherwise*).  A big part of your class should be learning *how* to count without needing to rely on counting with your fingers and toes or listing everything out.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have not shown any attempt to solve these
problems, there is no way for me to know which of several
approaches you are expected to take. I will show a couple
of approaches along with the numerical answers obtained.

That way, at least you will know the correct answers if
you follow @JMoravits's extensive clues toward a solution
via combinatorial methods. [By whatever method, my goal is that you will be able to solve such problems on your own. Like, say, on an exam.]

**Binomial distribution "with replacement".** If sampling with replacement (repetitions allowed), then the number $X$ of odd
items chosen from among $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ is
distributed according to a binomial distribution with
$n = 3$ trials and success probability $p = 4/7.$
The exact answer from R statistical software, where `dbinom` is a
binomial PDF, is shown below. Look at the binomial PDF formula in your text.

```
dbinom(3,3,4/7)
[1] 0.1865889
(4/7)^3
[1] 0.1865889
```

**Hypergeometric distribution "without replacement".** If repetitions are not allowed the number of odd items selected
follows as hypergeometric distribution with four favorable (odd)
items and three unfavorable items, where three items are selected
at random without replacement. Again here, you can check the exact answer against the appropriate hypergeometric PDF in your text.

```
dhyper(3, 4,3, 3)
[1] 0.1142857
24/210
[1] 0.1142857
choose(4,3)/choose(7,3)
[1] 0.1142857
```

**Simulation** of many draws of three items from among seven, of which four are odd, can provide useful approximate answers.
Let the population consist of the vector `c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)`, in which `1` stands for 'Odd' and `2` stands for 'Even'. In R, the `sample` procedure samples without replacement unless sampling
with replacement is specifically indicated. With 100,000 iterations it is reasonable to expect two place accuracy.

```
set.seed(1312)
pop = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
nr.wo = replicate(10^5, sum(sample(pop,3)==1))
mean(nr.wo==3)
[1] 0.11328  # aprx Answ without replacement 0.1142857
```

Now, continuing from above, we specify sampling with replacement, by using parameter `rep=T`:

```
nr.w = replicate(10^5, sum(sample(pop,3,rep=T)==1))
mean(nr.w == 3)
[1] 0.18699 # aprx Answ with replacement 0.1865889
```

*Note:* After the first simulation, the vector `nr.wo` contains
100,000 counts between 0 and 3 for the numbers of odd items chosen. Then the logical vector `nr.w0 == 3` has 100,000 `TRUE`s and
`FALSE`s. The `mean` of this vector is its proportion of `TRUE`s. (Similarly, for the second simulation.)